# Singular Values and Isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, svd, isometry, singular-values

Let $F \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times p}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$ be matrices, and let $r \leq p \land n$ be the rank of $X$. Suppose that $\sigma_{i}(FX) = \sigma_{i}(X)$ for all $i \in [r]$, i.e., the singular values are the same. Is it true that $F$ is an isometry on $\operatorname{Col}(X)$ (say with respect to the Euclidean norm)?

Stuff I have tried:

- Looking into SVD of $X$ and seeing what happens when you multiply it by $F$ -- in general, nothing useful happens, since left-multiplication may change the right-singular vectors.
- Using Courant-Fischer minimax theorem -- nothing happens because the dimension counts don't quite work, at least without some clever argument I can't come up with.

Nonetheless, it seems intuitively true to me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. The answer is **No**. For a counterexample, consider $X = diag(1,2)$ and $F = diag(2,1/2)$.

Comment: That is an entirely fair counterexample, and now I'm quite embarrassed at not having seen it faster... thanks!